# Problem with vote lock-ins

Tags: discussion

1. I upvote an answer that seems to be good
2. After some time, I find out that it has a subtle problem that makes it actually a bad answer
3. I can't remove my upvote

So, what can I do?

Comment: Just add a comment to make the author aware of it so he can fix it.  If he doesn't want to, or can't, then the comment serves to warn any readers.  That is a wholeheckofalot more productive than changing a number.

Comment: @Hans Passant, this will mean that the author of a bad answer will get all credit piggybacking on authors of better answers.

Comment: Hard to see your point or where "piggybacking" might come from.  You made a mistake, the author of the post had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Hans Passant, wat? The author of the answer made a mistake, I just didn't notice it first.

Comment: Thousands of ill-gotten points are awarded to bad content every day, no point changing the system so we can take away 10 points from a contribution with a subtle error.

Answer (score 7):

Is this a limitation of the vote locking system?  **Yes**

Is it a problem that needs fixing?  **I don't think so**

While it is not why the system was put in place, I think the voting locking helps encourage **good users** to think about their votes more carefully.  If you know you can't undo your vote, then you would be more careful to vote posts (especially answers)  unless you know you are casting a correct vote.

For a system intentionally designed with few checks and balances, it is useful to try to encourage responsible voting and not blindly voting on anything just because it looks good

Comment: People who have the mindset to blindly vote are just going to blindly vote and won't ever go back to fix an erroneous vote, because when someone blindly votes they just don't care enough to go back. I'm quite certain that the only people who are screwed by the vote lock-in are those who are *already* mindful of their votes. *They* are the ones who are going to go back to try to fix things when they realize they erred.

Comment: @Louis I certainly have no details to support this, especially given voting is not exposed, but I don't agree.  I think there enough users who vote based on instinct and their initial read.  I know it was a hard habit to train myself out of.